# Getting error while trying to Disable a button in DataGrid's Column in C# Windows Application

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, datagrid

I am facing an error while trying to disable  buttons within a datagird' columns.
The error is given below:

**[A]DataGridViewDisableButtonCell cannot be cast to [B]DataGridViewDisableButtonCell. Type A originates from 'IPMSGatePassManagementSystem, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' in the context 'Default' at location 'E:\Projects\IPMSGatePassManagementSystem\IPMSGatePassManagementSystem\bin\Debug\IPMSGatePassManagementSystem.exe'. Type B originates from 'IPMSGatePassManagementSystem, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' in the context 'Default' at location 'E:\Projects\IPMSGatePassManagementSystem\IPMSGatePassManagementSystem\bin\Debug\IPMSGatePassManagementSystem.exe'.**

Getting this error in this line:

```
if (GatepassNo != "")
                    {
                        DataGridViewDisableButtonCell btncell = (DataGridViewDisableButtonCell)row.Cells["Action"]; //ERROR
                        //DataGridViewDisableButtonCell btncell = (DataGridViewDisableButtonCell)row.Cells["Action"];
                        btncell.Enabled = false;
                        btncell.ToolTipText = "Gate Pass Already Created !";
                    }
```

For ease of understanding providing the class below

```
#region DataGridView Disable Button(To Add Disable Button Column)


        public class DataGridViewDisableButtonColumn : DataGridViewButtonColumn
        {
            public DataGridViewDisableButtonColumn()
            {
                this.CellTemplate = new DataGridViewDisableButtonCell();
            }
        }

        public class DataGridViewDisableButtonCell : DataGridViewButtonCell
        {
            private bool enabledValue;
            public bool Enabled
            {
                get
                {
                    return enabledValue;
                }
                set
                {
                    enabledValue = value;
                }
            }

            // Override the Clone method so that the Enabled property is copied.
            public override object Clone()
            {
                DataGridViewDisableButtonCell cell =
                    (DataGridViewDisableButtonCell)base.Clone();
                cell.Enabled = this.Enabled;
                return cell;
            }

            // By default, enable the button cell.
            public DataGridViewDisableButtonCell()
            {
                this.enabledValue = true;
            }

            protected override void Paint(Graphics graphics,
                Rectangle clipBounds, Rectangle cellBounds, int rowIndex,
                DataGridViewElementStates elementState, object value,
                object formattedValue, string errorText,
                DataGridViewCellStyle cellStyle,
                DataGridViewAdvancedBorderStyle advancedBorderStyle,
                DataGridViewPaintParts paintParts)
            {
                // The button cell is disabled, so paint the border,  
                // background, and disabled button for the cell.
                if (!this.enabledValue)
                {
                    // Draw the cell background, if specified.
                    if ((paintParts & DataGridViewPaintParts.Background) ==
                        DataGridViewPaintParts.Background)
                    {
                        SolidBrush cellBackground =
                            new SolidBrush(cellStyle.BackColor);
                        graphics.FillRectangle(cellBackground, cellBounds);
                        cellBackground.Dispose();
                    }

                    // Draw the cell borders, if specified.
                    if ((paintParts & DataGridViewPaintParts.Border) ==
                        DataGridViewPaintParts.Border)
                    {
                        PaintBorder(graphics, clipBounds, cellBounds, cellStyle,
                            advancedBorderStyle);
                    }

                    // Calculate the area in which to draw the button.
                    Rectangle buttonArea = cellBounds;
                    Rectangle buttonAdjustment =
                        this.BorderWidths(advancedBorderStyle);
                    buttonArea.X += buttonAdjustment.X;
                    buttonArea.Y += buttonAdjustment.Y;
                    buttonArea.Height -= buttonAdjustment.Height;
                    buttonArea.Width -= buttonAdjustment.Width;

                    // Draw the disabled button.                
                    ButtonRenderer.DrawButton(graphics, buttonArea,
                        PushButtonState.Disabled);

                    // Draw the disabled button text. 
                    if (this.FormattedValue is String)
                    {
                        TextRenderer.DrawText(graphics,
                            (string)this.FormattedValue,
                            this.DataGridView.Font,
                            buttonArea, SystemColors.GrayText);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    // The button cell is enabled, so let the base class 
                    // handle the painting.
                    base.Paint(graphics, clipBounds, cellBounds, rowIndex,
                        elementState, value, formattedValue, errorText,
                        cellStyle, advancedBorderStyle, paintParts);
                }
            }
        }

        #endregion
```

Please guide me to solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Before you instantiate the DataGridViewDisableCell you first need to instantitate a DataGridViewDisableColumn and give it a name.  Here is sameple code on how you can disable the button cell

```
 var data = dal.GetTempDataFromDatabase();
 dataGridView1.DataSource = data.Tables[0];

 DataGridViewDisableButtonColumn column1 = new DataGridViewDisableButtonColumn();
 column1.Name = "Buttons"; //<-- have you defiened the name "Action in your code?
 dataGridView1.Columns.Add(column1);

for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
   dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Buttons"].Value = "Buttons " + i.ToString();
}


 DataGridViewDisableButtonCell btnCell = (DataGridViewDisableButtonCell) dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells["Buttons"];
 btnCell.Enabled = false;
```